# Changing domains for multiple feature classes/subtypes

Tags: arcgis-pro, esri-geodatabase, domains

One of my data entry specialists copied over datasets from multiple sources that had the same domain name. This caused many domains to have ****_1, *****_2, etc. I was wondering if there is a way to clean this up the domains. While looking at the domains, there are some that have 4 different copies and this copy also applies to the subtypes. On some of our feature classes, we have over 20 different subtypes.

Simply, need to find a way to apply one domain over multiple feature classes/subtypes.

The program that we use is the ArcGIS suite of products.

Comment: Is it as simple Assign Domain to Field?  Explore [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/an-overview-of-the-domains-toolset.htm) in the help file.

Comment: Just to add to this, you can right click on the 'Assign Domain to Field' and select 'Batch' to run the tool in batch mode.  Then you can assign the domain to the same field in multiple feature classes (simultaneously, running the tool in batch mode just once).  It also includes an option to select subtypes, or use the 'Select All' subtypes option.